# Focus error in TextBox with AppBarButton - UWP

Tags: c#, uwp, focus, textblock

I am using this code to make a button in XAML within a MVVM project in UWP.

for this use this code:

```
<CommandBar Background="Yellow" >
    <AppBarButton Label="Pruebas" Command="{Binding cmd_Process}" >
          <AppBarButton.Icon>
               <SymbolIcon Symbol="Setting"/>
          </AppBarButton.Icon>
     </AppBarButton>
</CommandBar>
```

At the moment of "clicking" the 'Command' the method that I need is executed in the ViewModel, but I have to send a content of a TextBlock to work with it in the ViewModel.

All good, but at the time of sending it sends me null, so that I do not send null I have to change the configuration of the Focus to the TextBlock, but I have to do it first, and then execute the Command.

If I use a normal button to link the Command works perfect, but not with the AppBarButton.

How do I make the AppBarButton change the focus of the TextBlock before executing the Command? Or how do I control the fucus from the ViewModel, knowing that I have to call the page from the ViewModel class?

Comment: Where's your TextBlock? If you could provide a [mcve], it would be helpful to understand your question. Maybe, you did not need to focus on the TextBlock, there might be a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You Can Lost the Focus in the TextBox with te property:

```
UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged
```

use into the TextBox... Example:

```
<TextBox x:Name="txt_Name" Header="Name:" Margin="5" Text="{Binding PropertyBindingToViewModel, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can set the focus through ViewModel or even from your page class before executing the command or within the command function. with **Control.Focus()** method. more info in the links below : 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control.focus
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.input.focusmanager
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/communitytoolkit/developer-tools/focustracker